# javascript setTimeout stops working after including createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, innerhtml, createelement

I'm trying to incorporate a new slideshow on my site. The slideshow has everything I need except the option for "height = "80%"", i.e. I want the slideshow to scale with the browser because the new site design will sort of by like an android application; fully immersive.

Because the slideshow itself doesn't have this option, I'm creating a javascript code that will check the document/browser window size every 2 seconds and reload/resize the slideshow itself so that it always fits the screen. But, the problem is that the javascript will only run once, onload, and doesn't call "setTimeout" after I paste a certain string of code into the script.

So, the problem is that setTimeout actually STOPS working, so it has worked before, after I include this string of code:

```
var thescript = document.createElement("script");
thescript.type = "text/javascript";
thescript.innerHTML="jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/ArtGallery.swf', 'gallery/gallery.xml', {width: '100%', height: '"+calcheight+"px', background: '#000000'});";
document.getElementById('galleryid').appendChild(thescript);
```

The full javascript check function is here:

```
function getDocSpecs() {

    clearTimeout(t);
    var D = Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight));

    var Le = Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth),
        Math.max(document.body.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth));

    calcheight = (0.80 * D);
    alert(preheight + "_" + prewidth + "_" + D + "_" + Le + "_");
    if (preheight != D || prewidth != Le) {

        var thescript = document.createElement("script");
        thescript.type = "text/javascript";
        thescript.innerHTML = "jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/ArtGallery.swf', 'gallery/gallery.xml', {width: '100%', height: '" + calcheight + "px', background: '#000000'});";
        document.getElementById('galleryid').appendChild(thescript);
    }


    preheight = D;
    prewidth = Le;

    t = setTimeout('getDocSpecs()', 2000);
}
```

These two seem to not like each other:

```
var thescript = document.createElement("script");
thescript.type = "text/javascript";
thescript.innerHTML="jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/ArtGallery.swf', 'gallery/gallery.xml', {width: '100%', height: '"+calcheight+"px', background: '#000000'});";
document.getElementById('galleryid').appendChild(thescript);
```

and

```
t = setTimeout('getDocSpecs()', 2000);
```

I've tried to trick it by loading the slideshow first then calling the function, adding a click activated text, calling multiple functions, etc.

Comment: Why do you think you need to create a `<script>` element, add code to it, and append it somewhere? Just execute the code.

Comment: ..holy cow..., I wouldn't know where to start...

Comment: Instead of timeout, why don't you use interval? Or event better, why not window.onresize? Just add a throttle so it doesnt call a thousand times.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you don't pass a string to be eval'd to `window.setTimeout`, but rather pass the function itself; `window.setTimeout(getDocSpecs, 2000);`?

Comment: Why don't you replace your first snippet with `jQuery.flashgallery('gallery/ArtGallery.swf', 'gallery/gallery.xml', {width: '100%', height: calcheight+'px', background: '#000000'});`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two shouldn't effect eachother, but at the same time, you shouldn't need to use `createElement` for what you're trying to do.

I've tidied it up a little, separated bits into clear functions and removed the `createElement` parts. Hopefully you'll be able to debug more easily now. I've tried to keep the behaviour the same otherwise, though.
As mentioned in comments, you could also change to using an event listener for *resize*, which will save the function from having to be called so often.

```
var getDocSpecs = (function () {
    var t,
        pre = {h: -1, w: -1},
        getDocSpecs;

    function asyncFlashGallery(p1, p2, p3) {
        return window.setTimeout(function () {jQuery.flashgallery(p1, p2, p3)}, 0);
    }

    function dMax(nx) {
        return Math.max(document.body[nx] || 0, document.documentElement[nx] || 0);
    }

    getDocSpecs = function getDocSpecs() {
        window.clearTimeout(t);
        var D = Math.max(
                dMax('scrollHeight'), dMax('offsetHeight'), dMax('clientHeight')
            ),
            Le = Math.max(
                dMax('scrollWidth'), dMax('offsetWidth'), dMax('clientWidth')
            ),
            calcheight = (0.80 * D);

        alert(pre.h + "_" + pre.w + "_" + D + "_" + Le + "_"); // consider console.log
        if (pre.h !== D || pre.w !== Le) {
            asyncFlashGallery(
                'gallery/ArtGallery.swf',
                'gallery/gallery.xml',
                "{width: '100%', height: '" + calcheight + "px', background: '#000000'}"
            );
        }

        pre.h = D;
        pre.w = Le;

        t = window.setTimeout(getDocSpecs, 2000);
    };
    getDocSpecs.CANCEL = function () {window.clearTimeout(t);}
    return getDocSpecs;
}());
```

Comment: Like you said, the two shouldn't affect each other. I changed to another slideshow maker and the script works fine now. The reason you get the correct answer is because you provided some solution; the two shouldn't affect each other. This will lead other people with the same problem to just try a different slideshow maker.